# Java VoIP Recording

Tags: java, rtp, recording, cisco

i wonder if you can help me out with identifying a Java library that i can use as a network sniffer / network analyzer to detect Cisco SCCP packets and record subsequent RTP packets for a call recording application for Unified Communications Manager (CallManager).

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do this but you're going to run into some problems. Since Java is at such a high level (with respect to packet capturing), you're (probably) going to loose some packets.

The [Jpcap project](http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/Jpcap/doc/) may be able to help you out though.

After you've captured the packet, you'll have to analyze it. Jpcap provides [some of](http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/Jpcap/doc/javadoc/jpcap/packet/package-summary.html) this functionality but you'll have to go a bit further to detect Cisco SCCP packets and RTP packets.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. Please note that jpcap just sniffs the packet however it would not analyze it.

Comment: Right, that's what I said above, it provides some of the analysis functionality in that it gives you objects for each type of packet but beyond that you're on your own.